# Which external frameworks does Drupal use, if any?

Tags: theming, nodes

I'm looking for ways to prepare and ease a transition to Drupal.

My department is planning on completely rebuilding our custom CMS in Drupal. There are 4 members on the team, two programmers. I've been researching ways to ease the learning process, as only our manager is familiar with it and he's not a developer.

My question is this: Is it possible to integrate any of the specific technologies or practices that Drupal uses in generic PHP-based websites? For instance, Drupal 8 will use Twig.

Are there other technologies or plugin components that we can learn and use before we start the process of moving to Drupal?

Comment: The following url will also be helpful for drupal 8 beginners.
https://www.drupal.org/getting-started-d8-bkg-prereq . It covers drupal 8 module development.

Comment: Is it possible to integrate any of the specific technologies or practices that Drupal uses in generic PHP-based websites? It depends from what part of Drupal and from the web site. Are there other components that we can learn and use before we start the process of moving to Drupal? Drupal is peculiar in many parts; you need to learn them all, to master Drupal.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! The question is too broad for a Stack Exchange Q&A site. There are many details that are missing to make the question useful to future users too.

Comment: Some more research into the subject indicates that Drupal's components are largely unique to Drupal, so this question may not be able to receive the specific answers I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Theme-wise there are a couple of very good base themes that make use of SASS/Compass (and therefore Ruby) such as

- [Omega](https://www.drupal.org/project/omega), and
- [Zen](https://www.drupal.org/project/zen)

(I prefer Omega, having just discovered its power).

There are some good integration modules such as [LDAP](https://www.drupal.org/project/ldap) for single sign on, and loads of third party service integrations from paid services such as MailChimp.

But, when it comes to handling the database and rendering pages, the core system really shines.  I'd really recommend learning Drupal's [database API](https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/database) because it does an excellent job of defusing potentially unsafe queries and is quite easy to use once you get the hang of it.

[edit] Another resource I keep going back to time and again is the [form API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7).

Comment: If I've completely missed the mark, let me know.

Comment: The OP is interested in Drupal parts to use in a site created with PHP. ("Is it possible to integrate any of the specific technologies or practices that Drupal uses in generic PHP-based websites?") I guess the OP is planning to make a gradual transition to Drupal by starting with using parts of Drupal in the existing site.

Comment: @kiamlaluno. This is basically true. Mentioning things like SASS/Compass, Twig, etc. is what I'm looking for.